# Jquery Custom ScrollBar ( Malihu - mCustomScrollBar ) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, mcustomscrollbar

I tried to implement a custom scrollbar for a left sidebar with fixed position, but the scrollbar doesn't work. Who can explain to me why doesn't work? I tried to "force" inside position but doesn't appear nothing.

look at jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1tpaeb4b/3/

```js
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $(".content").mCustomScrollbar(
            {
                alwaysShowScrollbar: 2,
                axis: "y",
                scrollbarPosition: "inside"
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
#sidebar-left-container{
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    min-width:250px;
    bottom: 0;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #808080;
    padding: 15px;
}

#sidebar-left-container h2{
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.truncate{
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

body{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
  <div id="sidebar-left-container">          
   <h2><strong><span class="fa fa-comments-o"></span> Conversations</strong></h2>
     <div class="content">
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media messages">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href=""><img src="/img/avatar-small.png" alt="avatar" class="img-circle pull-left message-img margin-right-15px" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body position-relative">
            <a href=""><h4 class="media-heading"><strong>Alessandro Corradini</strong></h4></a>
            <p class="message-text truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed est elit, vulputate vitae dignissim non, varius vitae purus. Praesent quis augue malesuada, malesuada est eu, cursus metus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can customize the scrollbar by CSS only if there is no any specific reason to use Javascript.

Comment: Where's your fiddle?

Comment: I tried to "force" scrollbar with  'alwaysShowScrollbar: 2,
                axis: "y",
                scrollbarPosition: "inside" ' but doesn't work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your jsFiddle.

First off, you loaded jquery library over HTTP and jsFiddle doesn't allow that.

Secondly, the way you attach the `mCustomScrollbar` is somewhat invalid. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    alwaysShowScrollbar: 2,
    axis: "y",
    scrollbarPosition: "inside"
  })
});
```

Then give your `div.content` some limited height, so you can see the scrollbar working.

**See your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tpaeb4b/4/**

Comment: I have added a height: 100% in my code and works well! thanks so muck for the help. :)